# Asp.Net MVC using Tilde in href attribute for relative paths

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Using MVC5 and razor.

**Case #1:**

```
var url='~/path';
<a href='@url'>test</a>
```

**WRONG** I get: http://www.example.com/~/path

**Case #2**

```
var url='/path';
<a href='~/@url'>test</a>
```

**RIGHT** I get: http://www.example.com/path

Is there a way to have razor correctly interpret the tilde? in other words, if I absolutely want to include the tilde in a string as in case #1, is there a way to get it to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Url.Content()` razor method to get relative path like following.

```
@{
  var url="~/path";
}
<a href="@Url.Content(url)">test</a> // you will get http://www.example.com/path
```