# Setting relative path for href

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on RAZOR.

_layout.cshtml contains the following as a sidebar

```
<a class="sidebar-brand" href="../Purchase/Index">
```

It opens  https://localhost/Purchase/Index

It works well from any CSHTML page. However, if I click on Edit page, I can see above inside URL

```
https://localhost/Purchase/Edit/46
```

From this page, if I click on Purchase Link, then it tries to open

```
https://localhost/Purchase/Purchase/Index
```

instead of

```
https://localhost/Purchase/Index
```

Obviously, ../Procurment/Index will not work in this case.

How to handle this inside href ?

Comment: When you are using the related path like "../Purchase/Index" it will be appended to the route generated by the `routes.MapRoute()` call. Therefore you are getting the `https://localhost/Purchase/Purchase/Index` URL.

Comment: If it is necessary to reference to the `Index` action method of the `Purchase` controller use `href="/Purchase/Index"`. This is the same as `href="~/Purchase/Index"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacdaw. I did not realize this. ~ works

Answer (score 0):

Use `href="/Purchase/Index"` or `href="~/Purchase/Index`.
By the way, starting from MVC 4, **Razor** automatically detects attributes that begin with ~/ and automatically inserts the `@Href` or `@Url` call for
you.

See the following article for additional information:
[Tilde notation maps to the original URLs by using IIS URL rewrite in ASP.NET Web Pages Razor V3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/tilde-notation-maps-original-url)

And an additional post: [ASP.NET MVC using Tilde in href attribute for relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45597644/6630084)

Answer (score 0):

It is always good practice to use `@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")` in razor view.
For your case, it should be

```
@Url.Action("Index","Purchase")
```